# CreateDirectory not working for server path - c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to c++. The problem i am facing is with `CreateDirectory` method.

`CreateDirectory("\\ServerName\foldername\",NULL)` gives no error but it also doesn't create any directory. However if I write `"D:\foldername"` instead of `"\\ServerName\foldername\"` it works perfectly fine.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: UNC path has `\\<server>\<share>`, and you cannot create that with `CreateDirectory`, a share should exist on the server. You could create e. g. `\\Server\share\newdirectory`. Read on UNC paths, as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\ServerName\foldername\"` is not a valid Windows path

`"\\ServerName\foldername\"` is valid, but this is the name of the `"foldername"` share on the `"ServerName"` network host. This is still not a valid directory you can create.

If `ServerName` is a valid host name, and if `sharename`, is a valid share on that host, on which you have write rights, then you could create `"\\ServerName\sharename\foldername"`. But you can't create `"\\ServerName\foldername\"`

Thanks to Matteo for pointing out that in C strings, the `\` must be escaped to `\\`

Comment: You are right sir. That was my mistake. But still even "\\ServerName\foldername\" is not working at my end. I don't know what the problem.

Comment: There's also a problem of escapes here... To specify `\\servername\sharename` in a C string you have to write `"\\\\servername\\sharename"`.

Comment: @MohinderSingh : completed the answer

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the difference between **Fully Qualified vs Relative Paths**

For Windows API functions that manipulate files, file names can often be relative to the current directory, while some APIs require a fully qualified path. A file name is relative to the current directory if it does not begin with one of the following:

- A UNC name of any format, which always start with two backslash
  characters ("\")
- A disk designator with a backslash, for example "C:\" or "d:\".
- A single backslash, for example, "\directory" or "\file.txt". This is
  also referred to as an absolute path.

for more Information refer [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)